# Will I get OTA updates after installing Android L Developer preview?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, ota-update, developer-preview

I installed Android L developer preview on my Nexus 5. Now I was wondering if I still would get over-the-air updates. If not is there a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

For users who are using Android L Developer preview will need to reflash the phone and install the fresh build.

> If you want to receive the official consumer OTA update in November and any other official updates, you will have to have a factory image on your Nexus device.

[Official Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/android-50-lollipop-sdk-and-nexus.html)

Answer (score 5):

> For the developer preview versions, there will not be an over the air (OTA) update.

This is clearly mentioned in announcement at [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/android-50-lollipop-sdk-and-nexus.html).

So, when the actual Lollipop comes out on November 3rd, Google will create factory images for Nexus Devices and upload to [Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images). Fetch it and flash it again to enjoy Lollipop on your Nexus 5.